# How to do `sort -V` in OSX?

Tags: linux, macos, bash, sorting, cross-platform

I wrote a script for a Linux bash shell.

One line takes a list of filenames and sorts them. The list looks like this:

```
char32.png char33.png [...] char127.png
```

It goes from 32 to 127.
The default sorting of `ls` of this list is like this

```
char100.png char101.png [...] char32.png char33.png [...] char99.png
```

Luckily, there is `sort`, which has the handy `-V` switch which sorts the list correctly (as in the first example).

Now, I have to port this script to OSX and `sort` in OSX is lacking the `-V` switch.

Do you have a clever idea of how to sort this list correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do they all start with a fixed string (`char` in your example)? If so:

```
sort -k1.5 -n
```

`-k1.5` means to sort on the first key (there’s only one key in your example) starting from the 5th character, which will be the first digit. `-n` means to sort numerically. This works on Linux too.

Comment: Haha, I had tried that already, but apparently confused the dot with a comma. Thank you!