# erge text files ordered by numerical filenames in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, file, merge, sequential

Is there any way to concatenate multiple text files in numerical order of the file names with one bash command ?

I tried this, but for some reason, the first three lines are not in order

```
sort -n *txt > all.txt
```

Comment: Do you have samples of filenames? Which names wasn't in order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding this answer, only because the [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35126969/793796) suggests [a bad practice](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). & In future, Hellmar may land in exact same problem [I faced once.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15131545/793796) : [Cannot delete an accepted answer.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258602/deleting-an-accepted-answer)

Anyway, this should be the safe answer:

```
printf "%s\0" *txt | sort -zn | xargs -0 cat > all.txt
```

Here, entire pipeline has file names delimited by a NULL character. A NULL character is only character that cannot be part of file name.

Also, if all the filenames have same structure, (say file0001.txt, file0002.txt etc), then this code should work just as good:

```
cat file[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].txt > all.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for awnsering. I tried it. But it doesn't order the files :(
Maybe because of filenames : file1, file2, file3, file4, file5, file6, file7, file8, file9, file10, file 11, file12....

Comment: I use Terminal on Mac and the commands below doesn't order the files

Comment: You have `file` prefixed to numbers. See if your `sort` supports `-V` option. If yes, use `-V` instead of `-n`.

Comment: ls -1 | sort -n give me analyse_0.txt
analyse_1.txt
analyse_10.txt
analyse_100.txt
analyse_101.txt
analyse_102.txt
analyse_103.txt
analyse_104.txt
analyse_105.txt
analyse_106.txt
analyse_107.txt
analyse_108.txt
analyse_109.txt
analyse_11.txt
analyse_110.txt

Comment: Ok, I suffixed. That's was my mistake. Prefix it with automator got it work. How to prefix with bash command ?

Comment: If your sort supports `-V` option, you might not need to rename your files. If not and if you already have files created, you may rely on the perl based `rename` utility to rename the files

Answer (score 1):

```
ls *txt | sort -n | xargs cat > all.txt
```

This gets a list of all the filenames and sorts it, then uses xargs to construct a command line from `cat` and the sorted list.

Comment: `echo *txt` will output one single line.

Comment: @anishsane Good point, I edited my answer to use `ls` instead.

Comment: Tx, but doesn't work. It merge with this sequence : 0.txt 1.txt 10.txt 100.txt 101.txt...

Answer (score 1):

update for anishsane's answer.

```
printf "%s\0" *txt | sort -k1.thecharlocation -zn | xargs -0 cat > all.txt
```

`thecharlocation` is the first key you want to sort. If your file name is `file01.txt`, `thecharlocation` is `5`.

See also another similar answer from Nate in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265284/how-to-do-sort-v-in-osx).