# Concatenating 1.txt, 2.txt ... 10.txt into a single file

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have a folder containing files named "1.txt" all the way up to "10.txt". How do I concatenated these files in numerical order so that 10.txt is concatenated last?

Comment: See: [bash : merge text files ordered by numerical filenames](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35126745/3776858)

Comment: As an aside, if you created the files using `split` in the first place, it would ensure that lexicographical order will do the right thing.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done easily with [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html):

```
cat {1..10}.txt > output
```